# SAS Enterprise Guide customize interface color

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

Is there any way of changing the background color of SAS Enterprise Guide windows? 
I have spent more than an hour trying to find a solution, but no success. Unfortunately my eyes cannot take the white background anymore.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Folks - don't forget to edit tags in when you notice something noticeably missing (like [tag:enterprise-guide] was here)!  Anyone with >2k rep can do it directly, and anyone with <2k rep is welcome to do it as a suggested edit and likely it would be approved by others (or me if I get there first).

Answer (score 6):

This is for version 6.1.

For the process flow:

```
Right Click in the Flow Area->Background Color-><pick a color>
```

For the Program editor:

```
   Tools->Options->SAS Programs->Appearance
```

From there you have to set the background color for each element in the File Elements box.

Answer (score 0):

For Enterprise Guide 5.1

`Program --> Editor Options`, Appearance tab.

See: https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2017/07/03/sas-program-editor-tricks/

Answer (score 0):

SAS Enterprise Guide Customer Documentation [here](https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/guide/) for all versions.

[image: SAS EG Documentation]